# Paho-mqtt connect via ppp0

Tags: mqtt, python-sockets

I am working on an embedded linux based device that runs ubuntu. Now the device driver for the wifi is really crappy so I cannot create a hotspot so this device connects to another device which is running a hotspot. Now I am connecting to that device for some input but at the same time connecting to internet to send mqtt message using paho mqtt in python via a gsm modem. The modem connect to internet using pon command and it works nicely. But when both connections are running, paho-mqtt cannot connect to internet anymore. pinging using -I ppp0 works fine. I tried to bind ppp0 ip address to paho-mqtt client using the bind_address argument but it does not work. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: It's not totally clear what is running where from your question, but it sounds like you have a routing problem. Most likely something is changing your default route or you are not running with NAT and IP forwarding enabled. For both of those problems would be better asking on Super User

Comment: I am basically running two network connections. One gsm and one wifi. The gsm one is for internet and the wifi one for conencting to another device for taking inputs. When Both are connected, I can ping to gsm and it wouks but python socket does not transmit through ppp0 even though the binding address is the one for ppp0.